# Get data from database SQLite3 without Index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite, tkinter

I need your help to solve an issue. I would like to enter data in a database with SQLite3, but first I need to fetch data from there and make some calculations. Here I attach my code:

```
def run_query(query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

def validation():
    return len(name.get()) != 0 and len(quantity.get()) !=0

def addstock():
        time = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
        hour = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p")     
        query = 'SELECT totalstock FROM Stocks WHERE name = (?) ORDER BY MovementID DESC LIMIT 1'
        parameters = (name.get(),)
        lastrecord = run_query(query, parameters)
        total = lastrecord.fetchall()[0]
        if total is None:
            total = 0
        else:
            total = lastrecord.fetchall()[0]
            total += quantity.get()
        query = 'SELECT precio FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        parameters = (name.get(),)
        precio = run_query(query, parameters)
        pricequantity = precio.fetchall()[0]
        pricequantity *= int(quantity.get())
        query = 'SELECT precio FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        parameters = (name.get(),)
        precio = run_query(query, parameters)
        priceforall = precio.fetchall()[0]
        priceforall *= total

        if validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (name.get(), quantity.get(), pricequantity, total, priceforall, time, hour)
            run_query(query, parameters)
            message = 'Stock for {} added succesfully'.format(name.get())
            name.delete(0, END)
            quantity.delete(0, END)
        else:
            message = 'Name and Quantity required'
```

In the database there is the following data:

MovementID (integer), Name (text), Quantity (real), QuantityPrice (real), TotalStock (real), TotalStockPrice (real), time, hour

Problem is that I get an error for the lastrecord.fetchall()[0], it says Index out of range but I don't know why.

Other times, I have an error of can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple.

I do not know how to solve these issues as I am a beginner in python and programming.

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: If you're getting an index error on `lastrecord.fetchall()[0]`, that means that `lastrecord.fetchall()` is returning an empty list.You either need to prepare for that, or try to figure out why it's returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `lastrecord.fetchall()` twice. The first call fetches all the remaining records, the second call has nothing to fetch.

There's no need to call it twice. You already set the variable `total`, you don't need to set it again.

There's also no reason to call `lastrecord.fetchall()` and then index it. The query has `LIMIT 1`, so it will only return one row. Just call `lastrecord.fetchone()` to fetch that single row.

Furthermore, `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples. To get the value of the `totalrecord` column, you need to index into both the list and the tuple.

```py
lastrecord = run_query(query, parameters)
row = lastrecord.fetchone()
if row:
    total = row[0]
else:
    total = 0
```